# Como somar um valor ao atual em cada uma das linhas de uma tabela mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tenho a seguinte tabela em um banco de dados mysql:

[image: Exemplo da tabela]

Gostaria de um comando para executar no phpmyadmin, que somasse o valor atual da coluna rating_sum com 5, e rating_count com 1, ficando desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero adicionar esses valores (5 , 1) para todas as linhas da tabela, sem nenhuma restrição. Tentei algumas coisas que encontrei aqui no SO, mas eram exemplos pra exibir o valor total de determinada coluna, e não é o que preciso.

Como poderia fazer?

Comment: `SELECT *, ( rating_sum + 5 ), ( rating_count + 1 ) FROM TABELA`

Comment: @MarceloBoni olá, o comando que você passou, apenas cria duas novas colunas com os valores somados, mas não altera os valores já presentes na tabela, tentei adaptar para UPDATE BANCO.TABELA SET `, ( rating_sum + 5 ), ( rating_count + 1 ); mas dá um erro de sintaxe.

Comment: A ta, entendi, `UPDATE BANCO.TABELA SET rating_sum = ( rating_sum + 5 ), rating_count = ( rating_count + 1 );`

Comment: @MarceloBoni muito obrigado, funcionou exatamente como gostaria, pode adicionar como resposta para marcar como resolvida por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando desejar fazer uma atualização de soma (entre outras operações) de uma coluna em todas as linhas de uma tabela, basta referenciar a própria coluna no `update` sem definir um `where` (isso fara com que todas as linhas da tabela sejam atualizadas). Em cada linha sera usado o valor que já preenchido nos campos.

No seu caso, alguma coisa desse tipo:

`UPDATE BANCO.TABELA SET rating_sum = ( rating_sum + 5 ), rating_count = ( rating_count + 1 );`

Comment: muito obrigado pela explicação, exatamente o que precisava

Comment: Hesitei em colocar como resposta porque das duas uma: esse tipo de operação sempre foi meio que automática pra mim, acho difícil colocar em palavras, segundo que **provavelmente** já deve ter alguma coisa a respeito na rede, de qualquer forma criei a resposta como wiki, assim quem quiser atualizar a resposta, acrescentando mais informações, ou corrigindo o que eu "tentei explicar", ficarei grato =)